# mySQL query complicated join producing random and erroneous number

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

The following code is supposed to find electors that do not have a postal vote, do have a telephone number are not in possession of certain codes are listed in another table called voting intentions with certain pledges or are not listed in that table at all.

```
FROM electors,voting_intention 
WHERE
  electors.telephone > 0 
  AND electors.postal_vote != 1 
  AND (
    electors.mosaic NOT IN ('E1','E2','E3') 
    OR (
      electors.ID = voting_intention.elector 
      AND voting_intention.pledge IN ('U','W','X')
    ) 
    OR electors.ID != voting_intention.elector
  )
```

At the moment it is producing a count of over 2 million records many times the number in the database. Obviously something is wrong but I can't see my error.

Comment: Would it help if you added an explicit JOIN between the `electors` and `voting_intention` table?

Comment: Where abouts would it go

Comment: Add it to the FROM statement - `FROM electors INNER JOIN voting_intention ON electorsID=voting_intention.elector`, I think

Comment: `electors.ID`, `voting_intention`, `pledge` and `2 million records`! What are you working on?! :O

Comment: @AdnanShammout 2 million records is no surprise. The way he joins is `each row of electors combined with each row of voting_intention`. Like he says "many times the number in the database" ^^

Comment: @tombom, I'm more interested in the column names. They sound like something contracted with the government.

Comment: Oh, I see. The `!` after 2 million records was a bit misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM electors e
        LEFT JOIN voting_intention v1 ON e.ID = v1.elector AND v1.pledge IN ('U','W','X') 
        LEFT JOIN voting_intention v2 ON e.ID = v2.elector
WHERE 
    e.telephone > 0 
AND e.postal_vote != 1 /* do not have a postal vote?? */
AND (e.mosaic NOT IN ('E1','E2','E3') 
     OR v1.elector IS NOT NULL
     OR v2.elector IS NULL)
```

Comment: This looks like it should be the one. Its producing a few too many results. It might be on my end so I'm just debugging

Comment: Yes should be != 1. In this case we don't want them. v1.elector should be TRUE not null as we do want the result if it has any of those pledges. I reset your parameter to true, but its still giving me the same count so I think something else is causing a problem here.

Comment: Ive got it, the other mistake was mine it should not be in the mosaic or (with any of the 3 pledges or not in the voting_intention table at all)

Comment: ok, but i don't get your correction `v1.elector IS TRUE`. Isn't it an integer?

Comment: Yes it is. BLAST. Should be the V1.pledge that is true

Comment: well in the join there is `v1.pledge IN ('U','W','X')`, how can it be true after that :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you a missing the definition of the join between electors and voting_intention

I would expect to see something like:

```
FROM electors e 
INNER JOIN voting_intention v 
    ON v.elector_id = e.id
```

Obviously with the keys replaced with the correct one for each table.